# Can the "closest neighbor" algorithm get arbitrarily bad in TSP?

Tags: traveling-salesman

Let's consider the following simple algorithm for attacking the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem):

> Choose the pair of cities $(A,B)$ where $A\neq B$ and the distance between $A, B$ is minimal amongst all the distances of the cities. Start with $A$, then visit $B$, then in each step visit the nearest city not visited already, until there is no more city left.

Given $k\in \mathbb{N}$, is there a setting of cities such that the total distance travelled is more than $k$ times the distance travelled in an optimal solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an instance with $4$ cities $a, b, c, d$ and the following distances:
$d(a,b)=1$, $d(a,c)=d(b,c)=2$, $d(a,d) = d(b,d) = 3$, $d(c,d) = M$ for some $M>3$.

Your algorithm visits the cities in one of the following two orders:
$$
\langle a,b,c,d \rangle \quad \mbox{or} \quad \langle b,a, c, d\rangle.
$$

In any  case the cost of the tour is at least $d(c,d) = M$, while the tour $\langle a, d, b, c \rangle$ has cost at most $3 + 3 + 2 +2 = 10$.
This shows that the solution returned by your algorithm can be at least $\frac{M}{10}$ times more costly than an optimal tour. Pick $M$ as large as you desire, e.g. $M=10k+1$.

Theorem 2 in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4569756) shows that the approximation ratio of the nearest neighbor algorithm can be $\Omega(\log n)$, where $n$ is the number of cities, even when distances satisfy the triangle inequality

Comment: +1 --> Thanks for your intuitive example and the link to the paper!