# Nearest neighbor algorithm for TSP when triangle inequality holds

Tags: traveling-salesman

The output given by [this nearest neighbor algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142426/can-the-closest-neighbor-algorithm-get-arbitrarily-bad-in-tsp) for the Travelling Salesman Problem can be arbitrarily bad. In the example [constructed here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/142429/21156), the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) doesn't hold in most cases.

Let $L$ be the set of positive real numbers $r\in\mathbb{R}_+$ such that for every setting of TSP such that the triangle equality holds, we have that the length of the tour that the nearest neighbor algorithm gives is at most $r\cdot \ell$, where $\ell$ is the optimal (minimal) length of any tour.

**Question.** Is $L$ non-empty? If yes, what is $\inf L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $L$ is empty.

Theorem 2 in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4569756) shows that, for any integer $m > 3$, there exists an instance with $n = 2^m - 1$ cities such that **it satisfies the triangle inequality** and the approximation ratio of the nearest neighbor algorithm on this instance is larger than $\frac{\log(n+1)}{3}$.

Pick your favorite $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$, and choose $m= 4\lceil x \rceil$. By the above theorem, the approximation ratio must be larger than $\frac{\log(n+1)}{3} = \frac{\log 2^m}{3} = \frac{m}{3} > x$. This shows that $x \not\in L$.

(All logarithms are in base 2)